# Docker testing laravel project alway failed first time by SQLSTATE 2002

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using docker to run laravel project testing,
the command look likes this

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
docker-compose up -d laravel php-fpm apache2 mysql
sleep 4
docker ps
docker-compose ps
docker-compose exec laravel bash tests.sh

sleep 4
docker ps
docker-compose ps
docker-compose exec laravel bash tests.sh
```

but always failed in first time `tests.sh` and get message `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused` and sleep 4s to run second time testing will be success.
It's very weird, and I'm sure the all testing result should be the green light.

Here have some log and command output to help
https://gist.github.com/weretyc/9217c5c1775d1c284b6d525538817620

Any idea?